# compare data from 2 files and return the data thats not in either of the files?

Tags: java, csv, file, oop, structure

lets say i have 2 files with ids and dates column

```
file1:
empid1: date 1
empid1: date 2
empid2: date 3
empid2: date 4

file2:
empid1: date 1
empid2: date 3
empid3: date 5
```

so, now, when i compare the 2 files, my main goal is to retrieve those data that are not in the file 2 and vice versa.
Can anyone help me or guide me on how to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code, and what is the issue?

Comment: Do you mean you need to output only the rows which are not common to both files?

Comment: yes, output the ones that are not common.

Comment: Read file 1, store the lines in a list -> file1list
Maintain a separate list ->uncommon
Read file 2 line by line, if the line doesn't exist in file1list, put it in uncommon
return uncommon

Would be great if you show what have you done so far and issue you faced

Comment: files need not to be in sorted order, files are large over 7k entries, im working on 1.8

Comment: I am new to java, so gathering inputs and ideas on how to achieve this. and, yes ill try what @DeepanshuRathi has suggested.

Answer (score 1):

7k entries is not a lot. With today's computers having gigabytes of RAM, you should be able to store the entire contents of both files in memory so consider the following code (which is suitable for Java 8)

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Testings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path1 = Paths.get("path-to-first-file");
        Path path2 = Paths.get("path-to-second-file");
        try {
            List<String> lines1 = Files.readAllLines(path1);

            // Make copy of 'lines1'.
            List<String> org1 = new ArrayList<>(lines1);

            List<String> lines2 = Files.readAllLines(path2);

            // Now 'lines1' only contains lines that are not in 'lines2'.
            lines1.removeAll(lines2);

            // Now 'lines2' only contains lines that are not in [original] 'lines1'.
            lines2.removeAll(org1);

            // 'lines1' now contains lines that were not common in the original lists.
            lines1.addAll(lines2);
        }
        catch (IOException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> f = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "A", "B", "D" });
    List<String> s = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "A", "B", "C" });
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nonCommonLines(f, s).toArray()));
}

public static List<String> nonCommonLines(List<String> first, List<String> second) {
    List<String> nonCommonReturn = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (first != null && second != null) {
        for (String firstIterator : first) {
            if (Collections.frequency(second, firstIterator) == 0) {
                nonCommonReturn.add(firstIterator);
            }
        }
        for (String secondIterator : second) {
            if (Collections.frequency(first, secondIterator) == 0) {
                nonCommonReturn.add(secondIterator);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (first == null)
            nonCommonReturn.addAll(second);
        if (second == null)
            nonCommonReturn.addAll(first);
    }
    return nonCommonReturn;
}
```